# AJAX and JQuery to regularly load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I'm trying to automatically show stock results from an external page, using jquery and ajax.  I changed my original file to make it simpler.  Sadly, it is not working again..  Can anyone see what my problems are?  Thank you so much!
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Stocks</title>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">                 </script>
            <script src="projectstocks.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div>
        <content id="content">

        </content></div>
        </body>
     </html>
```

projectstocks.js:

```
    window.onload = function() {
var stocks = [];
var content = document.getElementById("content");
update();
setInterval("getData()", 1000);
}

function getData(data) {
content.innerHTML = "";
var tbod = document.getElementById("stocks");
var myTable= "<table id='table' border='1'>";
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var obj = data[i];
    for(key in obj){
        console.log(key);
        var value=(obj[key]);
        console.log(value);
        content.innerHTML += ("<tr><td>");
        content.innerHTML += ((obj[key]));
        content.innerHTML += ("<br><br></td></tr>");
    }
}
myTable+="</table>";
}

function update() {
$.getJSON('http://shodor.org/~amalani/AjaxTutorial/stocks/stocks.php?symbols=GOOG+CAT+FB', getData);
 }
```

Thanks again!  This doesn't have to be very fancy, let me know if there's anything I don't need.

Comment: What have you done to try to debug this? What does the develop tools error console say? What does the developer tools Net tab say? Do you see the HTTP request being made? Do you see the response? Are they what you expect?

Comment: you need first to `alert` the result or print it into the console so that you know if the ajax who failed or something else

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write the results to these elements which do not exist in your html:

```
document.getElementById("stocktable").innerHTML = table;
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "Last Update: " + d.toLocaleString();
```

add

```
<div id="stocktable"></div>
<div id="date"></div>
```

to your html.